# Reading an Asterix file from JSON output

Tags: python, json, file, parsing, format

Trying to convert a radar data file, that was sent to me in JSON format, to manageable DataFrame.

The first three lines of the file look like this:

```
{"id":1,"length":43,"crc":"D81B2DB5","timestamp":1617,"hexdata":"30002EFFD7021483000069E03BF78BE702A001E0FE2104B51D21020234269604D174E75DA008A50312B0620620B6","CAT048":{"I010":{"SAC":20,"SIC":131},"I140":{"ToD":0.8203125},"I020":{"TYP":7,"SIM":0,"RDP":0,"SPI":0,"RAB":0,"FX":0},"I040":{"RHO":59.9648438,"THETA":196.7376709},"I070":{"V":0,"G":0,"L":0,"spare":0,"Mode3A":"1240"},"I090":{"V":0,"G":0,"FL":120},"I130":{"SRLP":{"SRL":1.4501953},"SRRP":{"SRR":4},"SAMP":{"SAM":-75},"PRLP":{"PRL":1.2744141},"PAMP":{"PAM":33},"RPDP":{"RPD":0.0078125},"APDP":{"APD":0.0439453}},"I220":{"ACAddr":"342696"},"I240":{"TId":"AME4956 "},"I161":{"Tn":2213},"I200":{"CGS":172.92,"CHdg":248.0383301},"I170":{"CNF":0,"RAD":0,"DOU":0,"MAH":0,"CDM":3,"FX":0},"I230":{"COM":1,"STAT":0,"SI":0,"spare":0,"ModeSSSC":1,"ARC":0,"AIC":1,"BDS16":1,"BDS37":6}},"lat":38.585666818124,"lon":2.3784905351223,"h":3658.0244306503}
{"id":1,"length":40,"crc":"065756DA","timestamp":2468,"hexdata":"30002BFBB70214830000D2A000C8C0510A38E01804EA34239701803000000000004008BE00369EAE4624A0","CAT048":{"I010":{"SAC":20,"SIC":131},"I140":{"ToD":1.640625},"I020":{"TYP":5,"SIM":0,"RDP":0,"SPI":0,"RAB":0,"FX":0},"I040":{"RHO":0.78125,"THETA":270.4449463},"I070":{"V":0,"G":0,"L":0,"spare":0,"Mode3A":"5070"},"I130":{"SRLP":{"SRL":1.0546875},"SRRP":{"SRR":4},"SAMP":{"SAM":-22}},"I220":{"ACAddr":"342397"},"I250":[{"MCP_ALT_STATUS":1,"MCP_ALT":96,"FMS_ALT_STATUS":0,"FMS_ALT":0,"BP_STATUS":0,"BP":0,"res":0,"MODE_STATUS":0,"VNAV":0,"ALT_HOLD":0,"APP":0,"TARGET_ALT_STATUS":0,"TARGET_ALT_SOURCE":0,"BDS":"40"}],"I161":{"Tn":2238},"I200":{"CGS":11.88,"CHdg":223.1433105},"I170":{"CNF":0,"RAD":2,"DOU":0,"MAH":0,"CDM":3,"FX":0},"I230":{"COM":1,"STAT":1,"SI":0,"spare":0,"ModeSSSC":1,"ARC":0,"AIC":1,"BDS16":0,"BDS37":0}},"lat":39.543535327942,"lon":2.7284206653891,"h":4.2666605189443}
{"id":2,"length":64,"crc":"A45FA0D0","timestamp":2468,"hexdata":"300043FFF7021483000115A0896BE1B70AC105C8E01403BC4BB184508672CB482003C8480030A4018040FFD3C13A7FFCEC509E1A1F342037FF6008C1081E3CF54620F5","CAT048":{"I010":{"SAC":20,"SIC":131},"I140":{"ToD":2.1640625},"I020":{"TYP":5,"SIM":0,"RDP":0,"SPI":0,"RAB":0,"FX":0},"I040":{"RHO":137.4179688,"THETA":317.411499},"I070":{"V":0,"G":0,"L":0,"spare":0,"Mode3A":"5301"},"I090":{"V":0,"G":0,"FL":370},"I130":{"SRLP":{"SRL":0.8789062},"SRRP":{"SRR":3},"SAMP":{"SAM":-68}},"I220":{"ACAddr":"4BB184"},"I240":{"TId":"THY224  "},"I250":[{"MCP_ALT_STATUS":1,"MCP_ALT":37008,"FMS_ALT_STATUS":0,"FMS_ALT":0,"BP_STATUS":1,"BP":213,"res":0,"MODE_STATUS":1,"VNAV":1,"ALT_HOLD":0,"APP":0,"TARGET_ALT_STATUS":0,"TARGET_ALT_SOURCE":0,"BDS":"40"},{"RA_STATUS":1,"RA":-0.3515625,"TTA_STATUS":1,"TTA":84.375,"GS_STATUS":1,"GS":466,"TAR_STATUS":1,"TAR":-0.03125,"TAS_STATUS":1,"TAS":472,"BDS":"50"},{"HDG_STATUS":1,"HDG":84.5507812,"IAS_STAT":1,"IAS":271,"MACH_STATUS":1,"MACH":0.832,"BAR_STATU
```

I can see these lines contain the info I need, like callsign ("TId": "AME4956 "), heading and so on.
Is there a nice Pythonic way to get these values into a Dataframe?

Comment: Interesting to see that StackOverflow already can separate the values (in red) from the rest of the data! So it already realises the datatype as dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with the following code:

```
infos = []
with open('C:/Users/jobbr/Downloads/211201-est-000001/211201-est-000001.json') as fid:
    for ln in fid:
        infos.append(json.loads(ln))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(infos)
#print(df1)
# unravel this dataframe

c = df1['CAT048'].to_dict()                                   # The CAT048 field holds important parameters
for i in range(0,len(df1)):
    #print(i, c[i]['I200']['CGS'], c[i]['I200']['CHdg'])
    df1.at[i, 'ground_speed'] = c[i]['I200']['CGS']
    df1.at[i, 'heading'] = c[i]['I200']['CHdg']
    df1.at[i, 'ACAddr'] = c[i]['I220']['ACAddr']
    df1.at[i, 'ToD'] = c[i]['I140']['ToD']
    
    try:                                                      # not all parameters seem to be present always
        df1.at[i, 'flight_level'] = c[i]['I090']['FL']
    except:
        df1.at[i, 'flight_level'] = 0

    try:
        df1.at[i, 'callsign'] = c[i]['I240']['TId']
    except:
        df1.at[i, 'callsign'] = 'Unknown'
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is almost valid JSON, except the final line seems to be truncated.
Pandas can import dictionaries with almost no pain:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

infos = []
with open(infofile) as fid:
    for ln in fid:
        infos.append(json.loads(ln))

df = pd.DataFrame(infos)
print(df)
```

prints:

```
   id  length       crc  timestamp                                            hexdata                                             CAT048        lat       lon            h
0   1      43  D81B2DB5       1617  30002EFFD7021483000069E03BF78BE702A001E0FE2104...  {'I010': {'SAC': 20, 'SIC': 131}, 'I140': {'To...  38.585667  2.378491  3658.024431
1   1      40  065756DA       2468  30002BFBB70214830000D2A000C8C0510A38E01804EA34...  {'I010': {'SAC': 20, 'SIC': 131}, 'I140': {'To...  39.543535  2.728421     4.266661
2   2      64  A45FA0D0       2468  300043FFF7021483000115A0896BE1B70AC105C8E01403...  {'I010': {'SAC': 20, 'SIC': 131}, 'I140': {'To...        NaN       NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. Only the read is obviously not complete, because I am missing a lot of information. Should I try to repair the JSON file somewhere and if so; where?

Comment: The CAT048 field looks like it contains a nested dict, I shall try to extract that part again.